# S60 application - Symbian C++ - Exit button doesn't work

Tags: c++, symbian, exit, s60, carbide

In my Symbian S60 application, my Options menu works as expected. But the Exit button does nothing.

I am developing with Carbide and have used the UI Designer to add items to the options menu.

Does anyone know how to enable the exit button, or why else it might not work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you handling (in your `appui::HandleCommandL`) command ids `EEikCmdExit` and `EAknSoftkeyExit?`

```
    if ( aCommand == EAknSoftkeyExit || aCommand == EEikCmdExit )
        {
        Exit();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked inside the `HandleCommandL( TInt aCommand )` method of the `AppUi` class of your application? For example, in all UI projects I create with Carbide, the following is automatically present inside the `HandleCommandL()` method:

```
void MyAppUi::HandleCommandL( TInt aCommand )
{
    TBool commandHandled = False;
    switch ( aCommand )
    {
        default:
            break;
    }

    if ( !commandHandled )
    {
        if ( aCommand == EAknSoftkeyExit || aCommand == EEikCmdExit )
        {
            Exit();
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What CBA resource (softkey buttons layour) are you using? `R_AVKON_OPTIONS_EXIT`? are you handling the the exit commands in any other way? or are you traping the `Exit()` call? Are you even receiving the the `EEikCmdExit` code? If you have the [`commandHandled` boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359992/s60-application-symbian-c-exit-button-doesnt-work#360044), is it set to `EFalse`?

Answer (score 1):

Commands were being handled in my main view

So I changed it to this...

```
void CMyContainerView::HandleCommandL( TInt aCommand )
    {

    TBool commandHandled = EFalse;
    switch ( aCommand )
        {   
                // ...
        default:
            break;
        }


    if ( !commandHandled ) 
        {
            AppUi()->HandleCommandL(aCommand);
        }


    }
```

Thanks all :)